# XML XStream issues

Tags: java, xml, xstream

```
<PersonalVehicleCoverage>
        <EffectiveDate class="sql-date">2011-03-01</EffectiveDate>
        <ExpirationDate class="sql-date">2011-05-31</ExpirationDate>
</PersonalVehicleCoverage>
```

The EffectiveDate is of java.sql.date;

I am using XStream to generate XML from java objects using the following syntax:

```
xstream.toXML(data);
```

I don't want `class="sql-date"` as output in the generated XML.
How do I achieve that?

Comment: Is this not achievable in XSTREAM?

Comment: If you are interested in trying a JAXB impl instead let me know, I'd be happy to help:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html

Comment: Can you please show us your data object? The class attribute is output only if the actual type of the object does not match the type of the field declaration.

Answer (score 2):

This is what helped me resolve the same problem:

```
xstream.addDefaultImplementation(java.sql.Date.class, Date.class);
xstream.addDefaultImplementation(java.sql.Timestamp.class, Date.class);
```

Where `Date.class` is `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want is straightforward.
You create an XStream instance and configure it (in the example below I have to set the alias for the `PersonalVehicleCoverage` as static inner classes get serialized with the prefix of the containing class.
As the example does not use a package, it is serialized as you required. If your classes are in a package, you can use something like this to adapt the XML: `xStream.aliasPackage("pre", "my.package");`

Here is the sample code:

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;

public class XStreamDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    XStream xStream = new XStream();
    xStream.alias("PersonalVehicleCoverage", PersonalVehicleCoverage.class);
    PersonalVehicleCoverage object = new PersonalVehicleCoverage();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM DD");
    object.EffectiveDate = new Date(dateFormat.parse("2011 Jan 1").getTime());
    object.ExpirationDate = new Date(dateFormat.parse("2011 Jan 31").getTime());
    System.out.println(xStream.toXML(object));
  }

  static class PersonalVehicleCoverage {
    Date EffectiveDate;
    Date ExpirationDate;
  }
}
```

And here is the output of that example:

```
<PersonalVehicleCoverage>
  <EffectiveDate>2011-01-01</EffectiveDate>
  <ExpirationDate>2011-01-31</ExpirationDate>
</PersonalVehicleCoverage>
```